# not able to override bootstrap css in my style sheet

Tags: sharepoint-server, css, cssregistration

I have created my own stylesheet and wish to override some bootstrap functionality. I am referencing css in my .aspx page as below

```
<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="&lt;% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/MyStyles/Stylesheet1.css %&gt;"
  runat="server"
  after="pagelayouts15.css"/>
```

Now i want to override and remove this code from bootstrap-custom.css

```
*, *:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box; 
-moz-box-sizing: content-box;
box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

So i wrote below in my stylesheet

```
*, *:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important; 
-moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

But still not working. My page is still not behaving correctly. When i press F12 i see following

[image]

So it looks like that boostrap-custom.css again overwrites my css. How can i fix this?

Comment: Well, to mess up with bootstrap CSS is not that much easy. If you will change that `box-sizing` property, your responsive structure will not work properly(Read more here: https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). So in my case what I have done is simply overridden class where I need to apply custom css properties.

Answer (score 0):

try to add body tag in front:

```
body *, body *:before, body *:after{
...
}
```